# TinyMCE in MODX deleting rel attributes in my html links

Tags: tinymce, modx

I have an image gallery built with slimbox and it is in MODX. I need to be able to modify the link tags so the client can add in captions to each image. When you right click on an image in MODX in the TinyMCE editor you can edit the title tag which is where the caption comes from. The problem is when it is saved it is automatically deleting my rel attribute for the lightbox function.

I have checked the xconfig.js file in the TinyMCE folder but the rel attribute seems to be allowed. Do I have to edit this file (I have tried to no avail) or do I need to add a separate line of code to the actual page that the problem is occurring on?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What modx version? Evolution seems fine

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the default setup for TinyMce in MODX REvolution it turns out img tags don't allow the use of "rel" by default.

```
'img[align<bottom?left?middle?right?top|alt|border|class|dir<ltr?rtl|height'
    +'|hspace|id|ismap<ismap|lang|longdesc|name|onclick|ondblclick|onkeydown'
    +'|onkeypress|onkeyup|onmousedown|onmousemove|onmouseout|onmouseover'
    +'|onmouseup|src|style|title|usemap|vspace|width],'
```

Did you changed this to allow rel? If you did it might just be a caching problem so you might want to clear all the manager caches maybe even flush permissions.

Comment: I actually just changed the slimbox code to pull the caption from the alt tag instead. That way my client can alter the img attributes and not mess up the anything within the <a></a> through the text editor. Plus in TinyMCE the alt attribute shows up as "image description" so it's kind of dummy proof that way.